# BlackBerry application build unique identifier

Tags: blackberry, build, uniqueidentifier

I have blackberry application and I want to make different builds, which has different graphics and some constants. Also application name and icon is different. Different builds (of the same application) should be able to live by side on one device. iOS has special ID for that, in Android is renaming packgages needed, I also tryed renaming packages in BlackBerry but there are still some problems and I'm getting duplicate class error. So what's the unique identifier for BlackBerry application? and how to make safely different branded builds?

Answer (score 0):

Use ANT, get BB Ant Tools: http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/

I use a massive ANT script that does all sorts of magic for BlackBerry builds, copying different classes and assets around depending on the client requirements. You can have parameters for rapc in ANT like so:

```
        <rapc nowarn="true"
              output="${codName}"
              srcdir="${sourceDirectory}"
              jdehome="${jdeDirectory}"
              destdir="${ouputBuildDirectory}">
            <jdp title="${jdpTitle}"
                 vendor="${productVendor}"
                 version="${productVersion}"
                 description="${productDescription}"
                 icon="icon_inactive.png"
                 runonstartup="true"
                 />
        </rapc>
```

If you're doing different builds for different clients you really need to set up a toolchain using ANT

Comment: I have similar ant script, so what is that unique identifier? packages has to be renamed?

Comment: You must rename only classes, that implements Persistable interface.